# Duvida com relacionamento de tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql, relacionamento

Seguinte galera, tenho essas tabelas ai, estou estudando relacionamento de tabelas aqui...
Esse projeto não tem intenção nenhuma, a não ser praticar e estudar!
Eu relacionei a tabela categories e types a products como **1 para muitos**...

Onde um produto pode ter apenas uma categoria e tipo...
já tipo e categoria pode ter vários produtos..

Como produto nesses 2 caso ficou no lado de vários, então pelo q aprendi a chave estrangeira fica no lado do vários!

e na tabela addeds e deletions é apenas um complemento pra tabela products.. onde ficou no relacionamento 1 para 1...

a minha duvida é como relacionar de forma correta a tabela updates com a tabela products!
Já q um produto pode ter vários updates, e tabela updates pode ter updates de varios produtos..

Fiquei meio confuso, com esse cenário... Alguém poderia me falar como ficaria? e tentar fazer um resumo pra que eu possa entender um pouco melhor..

obrigado a todos desde já!

[image: Relacionamentos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque não uma relação de 1-M? O mesmo produto pode ser alterado varias vezes, por isso as entradas da tabela `updates` terão um referência para a entrada na tabela `products` à qual a alteração se refer.

Em modo desafio, o mesmo objectivo pode ser tratar as inscrições, remoções e alterações sempre na mesma tabela (`actions`, por exemplo) e diferenciar entre as várias acções por um campo.

Comment: isso mesmo, eu tinha chegado nessa conclusão tbm, acabei fazendo relacionamento de 1 para m! 

E mudei algumas coisas.. 
Andei estudando mais sobre modelagem.. 
E cheguei na conclusão que algumas coisas estavam fora de convenção..

No mais, muito obrigado, agradeço pela atenção e pela ajuda..